# Databases require upgrade or not supported

Tags: search, database, timer-service

My search stopped automatically crawling on Feb 28. I can still start it manually and it works but it doesn't work automatically.

When I went to Central Administration, I saw the following error: 
[image]

> Databases require upgrade or not supported.  
>   Severity 1 - Error  
>   Category Configuration  
>   Explanation The following databases require upgrade because their versions are older than the backwards compatible range: 
>   WSS_Search_PLSPF.
>
> Remedy Use Upgrade-SPContentDatabase to upgrade Content databases, or psconfig.exe to upgrade other databases. If some databases are too new, check the Patch Status page to find out if the current server are missing SharePoint software patches. For more information about this rule, see "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=142697". 
>   Failing Servers   
>  
>   Failing Services SPTimerService (SPTimerV4) 
>   Rule Settings View

I have almost no knowledge in SP administration and have no idea how to solve this or why this happened. If anyone knows how to fix this please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the SharePoint Configuration Wizard on your farm from one of the servers, it should apply any pending upgrades that are needed to the databases used by the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more post explaining same...

http://www.justanothertechnologyguy.com/2011/11/databases-require-upgrade-or-not.html

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Comment: The link leads to a malicious site and certainly not to any discussion of this topic.